# Sequelize - Create with nested includes does return nested object but won't create it in DB

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I got a bizarre problem, I want to create row with nested includes. The diagram looks like this (with more fields of course):

[image]

I'm going through deviceTypes and want to include sensorTypes and sensorMeasurements. In code it looks like this:

```
// global variables
const models = DeviceTypeDao.sequelize.models;

async createWSensorTypes(deviceType) {
  const transaction = await DeviceTypeDao.sequelize.transaction();
  const include = [{
    model: models.SensorTypes,
    as: 'sensorTypes',
    include: [{
      model: models.SensorMeasurements,
      as: 'sensorMeasurements'
    }]
  }];

  try {
    const result = await DeviceTypeDao.create(deviceType, { include, transaction });
    await transaction.commit();

    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    await transaction.rollback();
    throw e;
  }
}
```

The deviceType which i try to insert looks like this

```
{
  "field1": "someValue",
  "field2": "someValue",
  "sensorTypes": [{
    "sfield1": "some nested Value",
    "sfield2": "some nested Value",
    "sensorMeasurements": [{
      "smfield1": "some inner nested Value",
      "smfield2": "some inner nested Value"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I'm not getting errors of bad model (unknown columns or missing values) or non existing association, but in for sure here are my associations:

```
SensorTypeDao.belongsToMany(DeviceTypeDao, { foreignKey: 'deviceTypeId', as: 'deviceTypes', through: 'DeviceSensorTypes' });
DeviceTypeDao.belongsToMany(SensorTypeDao, { foreignKey: 'sensorTypeId', as: 'sensorTypes', through: 'DeviceSensorTypes' });

SensorMeasurementDao.belongsTo(SensorTypeDao, { foreignKey: 'sensorTypeId', as: 'sensorType' });
SensorTypeDao.hasMany(SensorMeasurementDao, { foreignKey: 'sensorTypeId', as: 'sensorMeasurements' });
```

And the result looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "59eabdf5-586e-4b0c-92ef-b3c140ca8d84",
  "field1": "someValue",
  "filed2": "someValue",
  "updatedAt": "2020-10-29T05:11:15.510Z",
  "createdAt": "2020-10-29T05:11:15.510Z",
  "sensorTypes": [{
      "id": "d6e2cbf9-09aa-490b-8415-ee9f998ad196",
      "sfield1": "some nested Value",
      "sfield2": "some nested Value",
      "updatedAt": "2020-10-29T05:11:15.635Z",
      "createdAt": "2020-10-29T05:11:15.635Z",
      "sensorMeasurements": [{
          "id": "34cf73eb-cbed-45c2-a7b4-894b0ae9ac23",
          "smfield1": "some inner nested Value",
          "smfield2": "some inner nested Value",
          //missing updatedAt, createdAt
        }]
    }]
}
```

It will return as it created all the fields but in DB i got only deviceType and sensorType. It will not create sensorMeasurement. But what is also interesting it will not return automaticly created fields such as updatedAt and createdAt. Any tips?

Comment: SORRY, this is not an answer. May be there is a bug within Sequelize or 'Pug' in my case as I have completely failed to get non-automatic items from Sequelize through model. Only the ID and created at are shown on Pug. My other added attributes are seen in parent object dataValues but Pug cannot render them. I have a pending question on that.